# sstabledump on ubuntu packaged installs

Tags: cassandra

According to the [specs](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/debugging-sstables-in-3-0-with-sstabledump), Cassandra should have the command line tool `sstabledump` available since its versions 3.0.4 and 3.4.

I cannot find this tool, although I successfully installed Cassandra 3.5 together with the tools.

I used the following source

```
deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 35x main
```

and the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install cassandra
sudo apt-get install cassandra-tools
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks,
medvekoma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `sstabledump` utility hasn't been added to the `cassandra-tools.install` in the cassandra debian install on trunk. I'd suggest raising a jira for this [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira).

Comment: Thanks mikea, will do so.

Comment: Jira ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11642 was created, a patch is already available.